# Flutter - floating circled widgets around one center widget

Tags: flutter

Is there, in Flutter, any chance to make floating widgets like Harmony OS devices list.

[Harmony OS - devices list](https://prognote.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Huawei-Super-Device-Harmony-OS.jpg)

It seems like widgets are "static", because of a tree layout. Maybe there is a library that is able to draw floating widgets.